# Computing the Mean of Twice-Measured Ordinal Variables for Individual Participants: Is it Valid?

Tags: mean, ordinal-data

I am conducting a 2x2 study with ordinal independent variables. Participants are asked to rate two different instances of the same independent variable condition. For instance, participants in the 'simple source text' group are presented with two distinct 'simple source texts' and are asked to rate both. We retain data from participants who rate both texts, indicating they perceive both as 'simple'. However, there may be slight differences in their ratings; for instance, they might rate the first text at level 1 and the second text at level 2. Our objective is to understand the overarching impact of the source text (i.e., the independent variable) on the dependent variables. Given this setup, is it appropriate to compute the average of the two ratings for each participant?